# change text direction in lyx

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I've just finished downloading lyx for the first time, and i'm having a bit of a problem with the text direction. whenever I'm trying writing something in Hebrew it's reverses the direction of the words, for example instead writing "אבג" it will write "גבא". also the direction of the tex is left to right (i want it to be RTL).

I've downloaded already the package i needed and followed the installation instructions and yet it doesn't work.
any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: There were a couple of these type of bugs that I think are fixed and will be in LyX 2.3.2, which should be released in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the text is marked as Hebrew (should have a blue underline is the document's main language is English). See [this](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew) and look for the instructions for setting up the `F12` shortcut.